# http-auth with express - login prompt popping up endlessly

Tags: node.js, express, http-auth

So I'm trying to password protect my node.js app with http-auth.
I saw many people that needed help with that too and tried multiple things. But now I'm stuck. The password is working fine, but the login prompt pops up again as soon as you logged in into the previous one. I can't get full access to my app.

My auth-part looks like this:

```
var preAuth = require('http-auth');
var basic = preAuth.basic({
    realm: "Private area",
    file: __dirname + "/htpasswd",
    //Type: "basic"
});


var server;
var app = express();
app.use(preAuth.connect(basic));
```

If I add a

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello from express - " + req.user + "!");
});
```

I can access the /test site no problem and it shows me "Hello from express - insertUsernameHere!"

But it won't work with my app. Is this because of my express.static? I'm not that good with javascript/node.js and still learning.

(And sorry if I upset anybody with my english, I know it is not perfect)

Comment: Your example shows what works, but does not show what does not, you need to provide the part that is not working or at-least minimized sample that does not work.

Comment: Well it works fine, but with my normal app it will pop up again as soon as I logged into the previous one. That is my problem.

Comment: You should show more code here...

Comment: I think this is the code that matters most, if you want more of the code you can take a look at Node-Red, I'm building my app upon this for an easier UI. http://pastebin.com/trLfDZcE this includes the http-auth part

Comment: That is better, but you forgot to say what does not work. I expect you to show me scenario that fails for given code fragment. So far it is ugly, but functional code fragment. Specially `createServer(function(req,res){app(req,res);})` could be easily replaced by  `createServer(app)` and same for https.

Comment: Well I get the login prompt, but it will keep popping up over and over again. I don't know what part of the code does not work (or if there is another way do achieve this, havent found one so far)

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined `app.use(auth.connect(basic));` **after** specifying the static files.

That's the reason your static files are not protected.

Make sure you set the authorization **before** setting the use of static files:

```
app.use(preAuth.connect(basic));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```